# Adding custom push notification sound ios5 not working

Tags: ios, ios5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have tried to get my custom notification sound working, I have tried a caf file, an aiff file and m4r file, but none seem to be playing.

My notification is coming through fine but the custom sound isn't playing, instead it is playing the default. My payload is:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"alert testing - hello!","sound":"testsound.aif"}}
```

From what I have read on here in other threads, if default is playing then the audio file isn't being found, but it is in the xcode project and I have deleted the app from my device and run it again.

Are there any gotchyas that I may be missing?

Comment: might help http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer:

When I was adding the audio file to xcode, I didn't ensure that "Target Membership" for my app was checked.

Once I checked that box, it works as expected